# Merging multiple associative arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Recently I've come across a question about merging multiple associative arrays into one.

Following is part of my code

```
//The Arrays ( Top 8 from the list )
$arr1["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Series"] = "Column1";
$arr2["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Series"] = "Column2";
$arr3["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Categories"] = "Column3";
$arr4["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Values"] = "Column4";
$arr5["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["SecondaryValues"] = "Column5";
$arr6["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Series"] = "Column1";
$arr7["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Series"] = "Column2";
$arr8["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Categories"] = "Column3";
```

I have tried grouping them up using `array_merge_recursive` inside a loop like the following

```
$arr9 = array();
for( $i = 1 ; $i < 9 ; $i++ ) {
    $arr9 = array_merge_recursive( $arr9 , ${"arr$i"} );
}
```

The `$arr9` outputs as following:

```
Array ( [XMLResultColumn] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [Series] => Column1 ) [2] => Array ( [Series] => Column2 ) [3] => Array ( [Categories] => Column3 ) [4] => Array ( [Values] => Column4 ) [5] => Array ( [SecondaryValues] => Column5 ) [6] => Array ( [Series] => Column1 ) [7] => Array ( [Series] => Column2 ) [8] => Array ( [Categories] => Column3 ) ) )
```

I expected the result to be:

```
Array ( [XMLResultColumn] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [Series] => Array ( [0] => Column1 [1] => Column2 ) [Categories] => Array ( [0] => Colomn3 ) [Values] => Array ( [0] => Column4 ) [SecondaryValues] => Array ( [0] => Column5 ) ) [2] => Array ( [Series] => Array ( [0] => Column1 [1] => Column2 ) [Categories] => Array ( [0] => Colomn3 ) ) ) )
```

Is there any way to produce the expected output as above?
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: can you paste, `print_r($arr9)` instead of `var_dump($arr9)`.??

Comment: Question updated , thank you

Comment: You're trying to achieve some *array_PUSH_recursive* result. Can't do that with native function (some hackish callback or nested loops would be needed). I would take step back and see if I can't gather that data correctly in the first place. If you add `[]` at the end of each assignment and get rid of array numbers (push into the same array) you'll get what you need (example: `$arr['xml']['0']['something'][] = 'string1'; $arr['xml']['0']['something'][] = 'string2'; ...`)

Comment: i have manipulated with code without any native functions, if u need i can post the answer.

Comment: Thanks for shudder for your pretty nice idea, I will give a try to your suggestion and see if it works.

Comment: Feel free to put your code here as the answer , Niranjan

Comment: @MiKeNeko but it uses 6 loops, it might cause performance issue. And it was 8 i reduced to 6, coz ur array is like that. And im sure its scalable.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes you're right. My array contain at least 100 members now and I think it may be growing sharply so I need to find some way to merge them smartly.  Six loops are too costly to me but I still appreciate your effort on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, it uses 6 loops.This is because of array structure. But nothing is hardcoded, if required, its scalable.

```
    $arr1["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Series"] = "Column1";
    $arr2["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Series"] = "Column2";
    $arr3["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Categories"] = "Column3";
    $arr4["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["Values"] = "Column4";
    $arr5["XMLResultColumn"]["1"]["SecondaryValues"] = "Column5";
    $arr6["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Series"] = "Column1";
    $arr7["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Series"] = "Column2";
    $arr8["XMLResultColumn"]["2"]["Categories"] = "Column3";


    $arr9 = $a = $a1 = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $a[] = implode(",", array_keys(${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"]));
    }


    $a = array_values(array_unique($a));

    foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
            if (array_key_exists($val, ${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"]))
                if (array_key_exists($val, $a1)) {
                    if (!in_array(implode(",", array_keys(${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"][$val])), $a1[$val]))
                        $a1[$val][] = implode(",", array_keys(${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"][$val]));
                } else
                    $a1[$val][] = implode(",", array_keys(${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"][$val]));
        }
    }

    foreach ($a1 as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $val1) {
            for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, ${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"]))
                    if (array_key_exists($val1, ${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"][$key]))
                        $arr9[$key][$val1][] = ${"arr$i"}["XMLResultColumn"][$key][$val1];
            }
        }
    }
print_r($arr9);
```

output is

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [Series] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column1
                [1] => Column2
            )

        [Categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column3
            )

        [Values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column4
            )

        [SecondaryValues] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column5
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Series] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column1
                [1] => Column2
            )

        [Categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Column3
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Nice, +1 for your effort. I will try it with my xml pool when I'm back to my office and to see if there is any performance issue.

Comment: 3 loops are extra because, i have not hard coded, u can add any number of index like 0,1,2,3,4 and for each index any number of sub indexex like series,series1,series2... etc.